# Did the Prophets fail?

Tags: prophets

As per the data, Allah sent a large number of Prophets into this world to spread his word and establish Islam. But it did not happen until Prophet Muhammad (PBUH).
So did all the previous prophets fail to establish the tenets of Islam? Can we say it like that they failed?